# user input check int only

Tags: java, user-input

I am trying to have my user input not crash my program by restricting what the user can input such as:

1. only being an int
2. being between 1-30

The code that I've written works only up to a certain point. If you enter something thats not an int it will check it and ask you to enter again. Then again if you keep typing anything but an int. I have another while loop if it does type an int, and if it's outside the 1-30 zone then it will ask the user to input again. However after that if the user types another "anything but an int" the program will crash. I've tried to combine both the `sc.hasnextint()` and the check for input between 1-30 condition but if i put the `sc.nextint()` before the `sc.hasnextint()` and the user enters anything but an int, the program crashes. If I put it after the condtion loop, then the userinput will not be declared.

```
int choose;
System.out.print("type an integer: ");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

while (!sc.hasNextInt() ) { 
    System.out.println("only integers!: "); 
    sc.next(); // discard 
} 

choose=sc.nextInt();

while (choose<=0 || choose>30)
{
    System.out.print("no, 1-30: ");
    choose=sc.nextInt();
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: "*the program will crash*" In what sense does it crash? Is an exception thrown, does the program go into an endless while loop, or does something else entirely occur?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:21)

Comment: The way i do it in my program, it wont work so i'm asking if someone knows of a different way to code that to make what i want work. For example:
type an integer: gfgh
only integers!: 43434
no, 1-30: ffgg

*crash*

Comment: That is unfortunately the most important piece of information you could have provided; add it to the question itself.  As for fixing it, you should try-catch your call to `sc.nextInt()` and then `continue` the (assumed to be existing) enclosing loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to combine the two loops, so that both checks happen every time the end-user enters something new:

```
for(;;) {
    if(!sc.hasNextInt() ) { 
        System.out.println("only integers!: "); 
        sc.next(); // discard
        continue;
    } 
    choose=sc.nextInt();
    if( choose<=0 || choose>30)
    {
        System.out.print("no, 1-30: ");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

After the loop exits, `choose` is a number between `1` and `30`, inclusive.

Comment: +1 for having an always-true `for` loop and having separate `if` conditions within it.

Comment: Based off of the new information OP has provided in a comment, I'd say that this answer will not fix the issue, because `sc.nextInt()` is failing to parse non-integer inputs.

Comment: @Vulcan That's OK, because unlike the OP's code this one does not call `nextInt` unless `hasNextInt` returns `true`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the second call to `nextInt` in the OP's code, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
do:
get number from user
if non integer format is entered{
number = -1;}
while: 1 < number < 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String choose = "";
    System.out.println("Test if input is an integer. Type 'quit' to exit.");
    System.out.print("Type an integer: ");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    choose = sc.nextLine();

    while (!(choose.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))) {
        int d = 0;
        try {
            d = Integer.parseInt(choose);

            if (!(d > 0 && d < 31)) {
                System.out.println("Being between 1-30");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Input is an integer.");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Enter only int");
        }

        System.out.print("Type an integer to test again or 'quit' to exit: ");
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        choose = sc.nextLine();
    }

    sc.close();
    System.out.print("Program ends.");
```

Answer (score 0):

See dasblinkenlight's awnser with the NumberFormatException catch. I was thinking of doing that. This also works too:

You need to combine the two loops like so:

```
while(true) {
if(!sc.hasNextInt) {
System.out.println("Only Integers!");
continue;
}
choose = sc.nextInt();
if(choose <= 0) {
System.out.println("The number you entered was too small.");
continue;
} else if(choose > 30) {
System.out.println("The number you entered was too large.\nMax: 30");
continue;
}
break;
}
sc.close();
```