# Why can't you compare array[n] to null in a while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, null, comparison

```
while (array[i] == null)
```

gives an incomparable types error.

I want to do the following:

```
  int i = 0;
  int[] array = new int[50];

  while (array[i] == null)
  {
     array[i] = console.nextInt();
     i++;
  }
```

Comment: What is `array`? Can a primitive have a `null` value?

Comment: You will need to use `Integer` class for your array, if you have to have this loop.

Comment: @Sotirios: `array` is an array. What is a primitive?
@PM: I declared the array as an int array. Is this what you mean?

Comment: It's one of two Java value types. Look it up.

Comment: int[] array = int[50]; is completely wrong! You can't do that!!

Comment: what is int[50]? Can you please explain?

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun Sorry. I corrected it so it reads `int[] array = new int[50]`... which is basically an array of size 50.

Comment: You corrected it but @SotiriosDelimanolis deleted his comment@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you cannot do this is because you have an array of primitive types. Primitive types must have a value in Java. This is because they are values, not references to objects.

An object such as an Integer, is a reference to a chunk of memory on the heap. It makes sense for that to not point to anything, thus it can be null.

In your case `int[] array = int[50]` (if it were syntactically correct), would never have a null element.

You're better off trying something like this:

```
int[] array = new int[50];

for(int k = 0; k < 50; k++)
{
   array[k] = console.nextInt();
}
```

It's much more idiomatic and anybody who reads your code will be happier with you.

If you try this, you'll get an index out of bounds error:

```
int i = 0;
Integer[] array = new Integer[50];

while (array[i] == null)
{
   array[i] = console.nextInt();
   i++;
}
```

So try this instead:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[50];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
   array[i] = console.nextInt();
}
```

If console is a Scanner, you should use:

```
int i = 0;
Integer[] array = new Integer[50];

while(console.hasNextInt() && i < 50)
{
   array[++i] = console.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: What should I do if I have 50 as a maximum number of inputted values by the user, but the user may enter less? How would I force those values into an array?

Comment: I'd have to know more about what console is.  Is it a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). If so, that can't return a null value at all, so you'll have to use hasNextInt instead.

Answer (score 3):

A primitive int cannot be null, hence the compiler error. Only object references can be nullable.

As **PM 77-1** has suggested, you can instead declare an array of `Integer` objects. Integer is a wrapper class for the primitive int. It can be assigned a `null` value.

By default, all elements in your array are valued 0 immediately after instantiation if you are using the primitive int. If you are sure that your array should not contain values less than or equal to 0, you can use this check: `if( array[k] <= 0 ) { ... }`

Otherwise, I would recommend using **usmcs**'s first suggested code block if you are sure that all values should be inputted by the user.

Comment: What should I do if I have 50 as a maximum number of inputted values by the user, but the user may enter less? How would I force those values into an array?

Comment: `console.nextInt()` should ensure the user inputs all 50 values. Otherwise, you'd have to assign default values to non-assigned elements in the array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487734/user-input-check-int-only